# Adjust conditionalPanel to show sliderInput

Tags: r, shiny

Friends could help me make my conditionalPanel functional. I made a conditionalPanel however I don't know how to adjust it on the server. When I press the option "No" I would like it to show the sliderInput ("Slider2"). The executable code is below. Thank you!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(
  title = div(tags$img(src="", align="right", height='50px')),
              sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 sliderInput("Slider1",
                             "Number of bins:",
                             min = 1,
                             max = 50,
                             value = 30)
               ),

               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(
                   radioButtons("filter1","", choices = list("Yes" = 1,"No " = 2),selected = 1),
                   conditionalPanel(
                      "input.filter1 == 'No'",

                    sliderInput("Slider2",
                               "Number of bins:",
                               min = 1,
                               max = 20,
                               value = 30)),
                 ),
                 mainPanel(
                   plotOutput("distPlot1")
                 ))))


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$Slider1 + 1)


    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
radioButtons("filter1", "", choices = list("Yes" = 1,"No " = 2)
```

the *values* of the radio buttons are `"1"` and `"2"`, while `"Yes"` and `"No"` are the *labels* of the radio buttons. So you condition should be `"input.filter1 == '2'"`.

Comment: Could someone help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62611894/adjust-image-that-is-shown-by-showmodal-on-shiny

Answer (score 0):

Your condition must be `"input.filter1 == 2"` and not `"input.filter1 == 'No'"`.
`"No"` is the name of the element, while `2` is the value (that is evaluated).

It will work with this modification.